# ng run test return error - TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular5, angular-test

I created the c3 bar-chart with angular 5.2.0. All are working fine. But I just want to run the test using karma and jasmine with `npm run test`. But I got the following issues. I hope it's related to rxjs function. But I can't understand the error core. Please help anyone to solve this.

```
TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:1466:80)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:128:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:118:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:92:1)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js.ScalarObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js:51:1)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:172:1)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:160:1)
    at MergeMapOperator.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:92:1)
    at Observable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:157:1)
    at FilterOperator.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Workspace/datawens-master/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/filter.js:61:1)
```

Comment: ¿Did you find a soluction for this?  I'm having the same error and I can't find a fix..

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue by making the following changes in my app.module.ts. Hope this helps.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    CameraPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
//  HttpClient,
   HttpClientModule,
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran across this problem while attempting to convert my tests to use `HttpTestingController`.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167709/angular5-ng-test-error-typeerror-this-handler-handle-is-not-a-function) answer simply suppresses the problem and prints it to the console.  There is a lot that I still do not understand for my solution below, but hopefully it can help someone.

The problem in my application was that I was providing `HttpHandler` in my `providers` list.  This was causing `_this.handler` to be an `HttpHandler` at the offending line in `http.js`, in the stack trace.

```
var /** @type {?} */ events$ = concatMap.call(of(req), function (req) { return _this.handler.handle(req); });
```

I removed `HttpHandler` from the providers in my `TestBed.configureTestModule` and then `_this.handler` was an `HttpInterceptorHandler` which had the appropriate `handle` function.

Comment: removing HttpHandler handler from app.module.ts worked for me

Comment: This resolved my problem when working with Angular Storybook, where I created an HttpInterceptor to capture API calls but was still importing HttpHandler as a provider in my story. Removing it from my story allowed my interceptor to properly handle the requests

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a subscribe without error handling can cause this, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49276737/6748184).
The answer in that link provides the following example:

```
user_login() {
this.userService.login(credentials).subscribe((res) => {
console.log(res);
}, (error) => {
console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

service call failedtypoerror this.handler.handle is not a function or

typeerror: this handler handle is not a function

As bill said i removed  HttpClient  and HttpHandler from provider list and add httpclientmodule issue will resolve