# Angular5 / ng test ERROR : TypeError: this.handler.handle is not a function

Tags: angular, testing

This is my Angular configuration :

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.2
Node: 6.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

@angular/cli: 1.7.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.1
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

My package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "ng2ninja": "ng2ninja"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.6.0",
    "yarn": "^1.5.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "8.5.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.39",
    "codelyzer": "4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-json-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "ng2ninja": "1.0.17",
    "protractor": "5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**I obtain this error message when i run the command 'ng test'** :

```
 TypeError: this.handler.handle is not a function
            at MergeMapSubscriber.__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_operator_concatMap__.a.call [as project] node_modules/@angular/common/esm2015/http.js:1174:28)
            at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/operators/mergeMap.js:109:1)
            at MergeMapSubscriber._next node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/operators/mergeMap.js:99:1)
            at MergeMapSubscriber.next node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/Subscriber.js:83:1)
            at ScalarObservable._subscribe node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/observable/ScalarObservable.js:42:1)
            at ScalarObservable._trySubscribe node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/Observable.js:171:1)
            at ScalarObservable.subscribe node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/Observable.js:159:1)
            at MergeMapOperator.call node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/operators/mergeMap.js:78:1)
            at Observable.subscribe node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/Observable.js:156:1)
```

This is my test:

```
import {TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {JwtInterceptorService} from './jwt-interceptor.service';
import {User} from './services/model/user';
import {HttpClient, HttpHandler} from '@angular/common/http';
...
     it('should authenticate a user', () => {
        // spy on the store method
        spyOn(userService, 'storeLoggedInUser');

        const credentials = {login: 'toto', password: 'titi'};
        let actualUser;
        userService.login(credentials).subscribe(fetchedUser => actualUser = fetchedUser);
    ...
      });
```

After analyze and debug, the problem comes from the call of the "login" method of the User Service.

Having browsed of numerous post (and solutions) i do not understand the real origin of my error message.

This is my User Service :

```
 login(credentials): Observable<User> {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    var paramCredentials = "grant_type=password"
      + "&credentials=true"
      + "&scope=read write"
      + "&accept=application/json"
      + "&username=" + credentials.username
      + "&password=" + credentials.password;

    return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.oAuthUrl}/oauth/token`, paramCredentials, {headers: headers}).pipe(
      tap(user => this.storeLoggedInUser(user))
    );
  }

 storeLoggedInUser(user) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.jwtInterceptorService.setJwtToken(user.token);
  }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please add error handler in your component.ts where you are calling this 
login(credentials) method.

```
user_login() {
this.userService.login(credentials).subscribe((res) => {
console.log(res);
}, (error) => {
console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I believe it only works to catch the error and print it to the console. It does not solve the underlying problem. If you look in the console the error is just being logged now.

Answer (score 48):

For me, this issue came from trying to include `HttpClient` and `HttpHandler` in my providers like so:

```
providers: [
    HttpClient,
    HttpHandler
]
```

This kept throwing errors along the lines of `_TypeError: this.handle.handler is not a function`

To fix this, I found I could remove `HttpClient` and `HttpHandler` from the providers and instead add `HttpClientTestingModule` to my imports like so:

```
imports: [
    HttpClientTestingModule
]
```

This solved this particular error for me in my Karma unit tests for Angular 7.

Comment: This was my issue! In my case, I used HttpClientModule in my imports, and that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: `import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';`

Comment: It's working for Angular 11 too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup. Its working Angular 13.2.6 too. Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 2):

The verified 'answer' is actually catching the error instead of fixing it.

As found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828409/10772249), you need to replace your imports:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHandler} from '@angular/common/http';
```

with

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Also replace TestBed testing module's providers:

```
imports: [],
providers: [HttpClient, HttpHandler]
```

with:

```
imports: [HttpClientModule],
        providers: []
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this problem while attempting to convert my tests to use `HttpTestingController`.  I believe the accepted answer simply suppresses the problem and prints it to the console.  There is a lot that I still do not understand for my solution below, but hopefully it can help someone.

The problem in my application was that I was providing `HttpHandler` in my `providers` list.  This was causing `_this.handler` to be an `HttpHandler` at the offending line in `http.js`, in the stack trace.

```
var /** @type {?} */ events$ = concatMap.call(of(req), function (req) { return _this.handler.handle(req); });
```

I removed `HttpHandler` from the providers in my `TestBed.configureTestModule` and then `_this.handler` was an `HttpInterceptorHandler` which had the appropriate `handle` function.

Answer (score 1):

To make the ***[HttpClient and HttpHandler]*** works, you only need to add the:

```
imports: [HttpClientModule]
```

, and remove:

```
providers: [HttpClient, HttpHandler]
```

Because the imports that you need inside of the providers in your module component, you need to add them to the import section of the test bed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you not use HttpHandler and Angular cant find this.

Try to remove HttpHandler from "import" and "providers" in your app.module.ts:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
...
providers: [HttpClient],
```

Comment: For later angular (6+ etc) it's HttpClientModule that needs to be removed from your spec file.