# Angular TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to run my tests in angular, but apparently i got an error like:

```
TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:1464:80)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:128:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:118:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:92:1)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js.ScalarObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js:51:1)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:172:1)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:160:1)
    at MergeMapOperator.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:92:1)
    at Observable.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:157:1)
    at FilterOperator.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/filter.js:61:1)
```

I did not change anything in my tests, but in my component I did add a new import: `import {Router} from "@angular/router";` and of course in my tests i did add `RouterModule` in imports. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular5 / ng test ERROR : TypeError: this.handler.handle is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167709/angular5-ng-test-error-typeerror-this-handler-handle-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not mock the methods used in my component. Mocking properly did solve the problem.